# In Python, how to join a list of strings with a regular expression as separator without escaping with the backslash character

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to concatenate several regular expressions with an arbitrary number of spaces in them, which I define by the variable

```
SPACES = "\s*"
```

However, if I try

```
SPACES.join(['from','till'])
```

I get

```
'from\\s*till'
```

with an additional backslash character in between. Is it possible to use the `join` method without inserting the additional `\` (so that the result is `'from\s*till'`)?

Comment: how are you 'getting' that output?

Comment: `SPACES = "\s*"` isn't valid Python

Comment: @cricket_007 - i'm confused, why should it not be valid?

Comment: @Christian The backslash needs escaped when not a raw string, right?

Comment: @cricket_007 I think it only needs to be escaped, if it would "break" the end of the string, like `SPACES = "\"` - this backslash would escape the ending `"` and thus produce an error. But the original `SPACES = "\s*"` works for me (python 3.5.2), and the backslash gets automatically escaped, so that SPACES contains `'\\s*'` and `print(SPACES)` returns the original `\s*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just observing the difference between a string object's `__repr__` and its `__str__` representation. The former shows special characters in their escaped form (the form of the literal you could/should use to instantiate the same string object), the latter doesn't:

```
> SPACES = "\s*"
> pat = SPACES.join(['ab', 'cd'])
> pat
'ab\\s*cd'  # == repr(pat)
> print pat
ab\s*cd     # == str(pat)
# re.match(pat, 'ab   cd') matches as expected
```

As has been mentioned in other answers, `'\s'` is not a valid escape sequence, hence the backslash is taken as a literal backslash which can also be be given as the literal `'\\'`:

```
> '\s*' == '\\s*'
True
> r'\'  # not a valid raw string! -> error
```

Comment: Indeed I was 'getting' it from the iPython terminal, which shows the `__repr__` representation.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
SPACES = "\s*"  # not what you think
```

Python tries to escape `s`, but since it's not a valid escape sequence it gives up and interprets the whole string as `"\\s*"`. This way, you're relying on a corner case, which makes your code difficult to understand. Instead, you should be using the proper form:

```
SPACES = r"\s*"  # same as "\\s*" and also shows intent
```

The bottom line is that `'\s'` is not a proper value, so Python will always convert it to `'\\s'` and therefore, you'll never see `'\s'` anywhere in an output string. The result you expect (`'from\s*till'`) is impossible, unless it's interpreted as an r-string (`r'from\s*till'`).

Answer (score 1):

You get `'from\\s*till'` when printing because `\s` it's not a valid escape sequence (see valid escape sequences [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)) so Python assumes you want a literal backslash (which you do) and escapes it.

Either way, the final string is the string you need, you can verify this by checking that `len(SPACES.join(['from','till']))` is 11 and not 12.